# Scraping un-closed meta tags with BS4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to get the content of a meta tag. The problem is that BS4 can't parse the tag properly on some sites, where the tag is not closed as it should be. With tags as the example below, the output of my function includes tons of clutter including other tags such as scripts, links, etc. I believe the browser closes automatically the meta tag somewhere in the end of the head and this behavior confuses BS4.

My code works with this:

```
<meta name="description" content="content" />
```

and doesn't work with:

```
<meta name="description" content="content">
```

Here is the code of my BS4 function:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = BeautifulSoup(open('/path/file.html'), 'html.parser')
desc = html.find(attrs={'name':'description'})

print(desc)
```

Any way to make it work with those un-closed meta tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`html5lib` or `lxml` parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) would handle the problem properly:

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   ...: 
   ...: data = """
   ...: <html>
   ...:     <head>
   ...:         <meta name="description" content="content">
   ...:         <script>
   ...:             var i = 0;
   ...:         </script>
   ...:     </head>
   ...:     <body>
   ...:         <div id="content">content</div>
   ...:     </body>
   ...: </html>"""
   ...: 

In [2]: BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser').find(attrs={'name': 'description'})
Out[2]: <meta content="content" name="description">\n<script>\n            var i = 0;\n        </script>\n</meta>

In [3]: BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib').find(attrs={'name': 'description'})
Out[3]: <meta content="content" name="description"/>

In [4]: BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml').find(attrs={'name': 'description'})
Out[4]: <meta content="content" name="description"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having get something new and hope it can give you some help, i think every time BeautifulSoup find an element without a proper end tag, then it will continue searching the next and next element until its parent tag end tag.Maybe you still don't understand my thought, and here i made a little demo:

```
    hello.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <meta name="description" content="content">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <div>
    <p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b>

    <p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
    <a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
    <a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
    <a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
    and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>
    </p></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and run like you done before and find result below:

```
<meta content="content" name="description">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Title</title>
</meta></head>
<body>
...
</div></body>
</meta>
```

ok! BeautifulSoup generate the end meta tag automatically and whose position is after the `</body>` tag, but still can not see meta's parent end tag `</html>`, so what i mean is that end tag should reflect as the same position as its start tag. But i still can not convince myself such opinion so i make a test, delete `<p class='title'>` end tag so there is only one `</p>` tag in `<div>...</div>`, but after running

`c = soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class':'title'})
print(c[0])`

there are two `</p>` tags in result. So that's true as i said previously.